# Engineering from or Engineering in

Tags: single-word-requests, prepositions, orthography

Should i write

> Bachelor of Engineering from [Place]

or

> Bachelor of Engineering in [Place]

Seems both sound right to me, or might be i am not good in my English language usage.

Answer (score 6):

I suppose the place in brackets refers to an academic institution. The best option is to use your first example. The use of the preposition **in** would make me expect some information on specialisation in a particular branch of engineering.

Comment: yeah my inner mind tells me 1st is right choice. Place refers to the institution of study.Thanks

Comment: @Deeptechtons, you may use "at"

Answer (score 1):

He took a master's degree in economics **at** Yale.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on the verb. Here are two examples that sound right to my (likely typical American ear--born and raised in New York, went to college and lived in California for 30 years).

She received her Master's of Electrical Engineering from Stanford University.

He worked towards his Bachelor's of Science in Economics at New York University