# Does one hold a M.A. 'in' something or 'of' something?

Tags: prepositions

In reading a curriculum vitae, I noticed an author used both

- 2013 M.A. of Information Science

and

- 2008 M.A. in Philosophy.

Is there any logic to this? Which one should be preferred for academic cv's?

Comment: You might have a look [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75097/bachelor-of-vs-bachelor-in/75099).

Comment: I also wonder what kind of guidance you would have received at [academia.SE] (but please don't cross-post).

Answer (score 3):

In my neck of the woods (NAmer) I've only ever heard M.A. in.  The reason is that M.A. is usually expanded in English as Master of Arts, and Master of Arts of Information Science or Master of Arts of Philosophy is wrong, because the second thing is part of the first (philosophy is part of the arts) and not the other way around.

It all gets pretty complicated pretty quickly.  Philosophy is actually more in the humanities than in the arts, but you can't even say 'philosophy is a humanity', because humanity is never singular in that sense.

My advice is to stick to the standard jargon, which is 'in.'

Comment: It may also depend on what the awarding institution uses (although *in* is far more widespread. There may be no institution which uses *of* for the reason you state).